# What is the value of $ \angle x $ shown below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: AB=CF

[image]

My progress:
This is a typical Peruvian exercise where the solutions are provided by auxiliary lines. I tried one way but I didn't find the solution

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct equilateral triangle $ABE$. Because $\angle AEB=2 \angle BCA$, $E$ is the circumcenter of $ABC$. 
Thus, $AB=FC=CE=BE=AE$.

$\angle EAF=60^\circ-24^\circ=36^\circ, \angle AEC=180^\circ-72^\circ=108^\circ, \angle BEC=108^\circ-60^\circ=48^\circ, $ $\angle ECB=90^\circ-24^\circ=66^\circ, \angle ACE=36^\circ, \angle CFE=72^\circ, \angle FEA=36^\circ \implies AF=FE$

Therefore $\triangle ABF \cong \triangle BFE$ (SSS)

Finally, $2\angle AFB=360^\circ-108^\circ, \angle AFB=126^\circ=x+30^\circ, x=96^\circ$

[image]

Comment: @petaarantes Thanks! You hinted that additional construction will be necessary so I was looking for it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As can be seen AB is tangent on circumcircle of triangle BCD and we have:

$\angle ABC=180-(24+30)=126^o$

$\angle ABD=\angle BCD=30^o$

$\rightarrow \angle DBC=126-30=96^o$