# What's the measure of $\angle x$ in thefigure below?

Tags: plane-geometry

For reference: Calculate $x~ if AE = BC, and AD = BE$
[image]

My progress:
I tried for auxiliary lines...parallel to BC by A and parallel to BE by A... forming the parallelograms...I completed the Angles but I was unsuccessful...but I believe the solution is in the auxiliary lines

[image]

For illustration...DR SK's resolution
[image]

Comment: This is similar to this question of yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4257751/947379 The only difference is you have to apply that method twice, like MOBINULS's answer does.

Comment: @ACB ...well remembered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the circumcentre of $\triangle ABC$ be $O$. $\triangle OBC$ is equilateral.

$\Rightarrow AE=BC=AO$

$\triangle AOE$ is isosceles. Through angle chasing, $\angle BOE=\angle COE=30^{\circ}$ and thereafter $BE=EC$ and $\angle BEA=40^{\circ}$.

Let the circumcentre of $\triangle ABE$ be $P$. Again, $\triangle PBE$ is equilateral, and through angle chasing, $PB$ passes through $D$. Hence, $x=60^{\circ}$.